# Is it safe to store the user object in the session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I saw many people who store only the id, that's why my question. Can I store the user object instead of just the id?

Comment: The user object is always available from the `HttpContext`, why would you need to store it in the session?

Comment: I wouldn't store the user object or the user id. `userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();`

Comment: The user principle is constructed on every request and is only meant to exist for the lifetime of the request.  Storing it in the session *may* cause problems by retaining references to stale data.

Comment: Im not using Identity

Comment: No one is talking about Asp.Net Identity.  We are talking about MVC security principals.  `User` is a property every MVC controller has.  That same `User` object is available from the `HttpContext`, and has a property `Identity`, which *identifies the user*, as its name implies.